# jQuery: update array in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

`array` - multidimensional array:

```
array[0] = [["1","2","3"],["1","2","3"],["1","2","3"]];
```

I need to put this array into cookie (`$.cookie('myCookie', JSON.stringify(array))`)

Now is the interesting part:

I need to maintain `myCookie` and put new data in it.

If newly generated `array` has any new data (elements), i need to pull new elements from array and add them to `myCookie`

What is the most elegant way to do that?

Comment: deserialize it, change it, reserialize it, and set it. How else would you do it?

Comment: @KevinB convert an `array` into object, `JSON.parse('myCookie')` and in a loop check every item in array if its exists in `myCookie`? (you are loosing me already but okay..) and then? Third object for new items?

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is to do it the same way you set it in the first place - overwrite your cookie with the new array values...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it, in step format:

1. Create a JSON version of your array `jsonArray`.
2. Pull down the cookie in JSON format
3. Without deserializing it, compare it to `jsonArray`.
4. If the strings aren't the same, set the cookie to be `jsonArray`.
5. Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: The problem is #5 'Otherwise' i need to pull changes from jsonArray and add them into cookie

Comment: @rinchik: No, because if the arrays **don't not** match then they are the same and nothing has changed. If nothing has changed you have no reason to add any changes to the cookie. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, I don't know about using cookies on client-side storage with a client-side language. That was really made for php to handle.

You should look into [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) for stuff like that, it is much more convenient.

```
localStorage['item'] = "Hello world";
alert(localStorage['item']); // Hello World

localStorage['item'] += "!!!";
alert(localStorage['item']); // Hello World!!!

localStorage['item'] = "Good bye";
alert(localStorage['item']); // good bye

var obj = {0:{text:"Hello"}, 1:{text:"World"}};
localStorage['item'] = JSON.stringify(obj);
JSON.parse(localStorage['item']); // {0:{text:"Hello"}, 1:{text:"World"}}
```

`sessionStorage` is  similar to `localStorage`, but persists only until the browser or tab is closed.

---

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var a=[];
a[0]= [["1","2","3"],["1","2","3"],["1","2","3"]];
a[1]= [["8","9","9"],["5","6","7"]];

var json_string_old=JSON.stringify(a); 

    //set myCookie
    $.cookie('myCookie',json_string_old); 

    //change the value of the array as per your requirments
   a[1]=[["2","2","2"],["2","2","2"]];
   a[2]=[["4","4","4"],["4","4","4"]];
    //convert it again to JSON String
var json_string_new=JSON.stringify(a);

    //now compafre & update accordingly
    if(json_string_new === json_string_old){
        console.log("same no need to update cookie");
    }else{
        console.log("different ok lets update the cookie");
       $.cookie('myCookie',json_string_new);     
    }    


});
```